# After wordpress migration my port is blocked and site refused connection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, centos, vps

I bought VPS on OVH and moved site. First I imported the database, then I uploaded the whole wordpress on FTP, I changed the login details to the database in the wp-config and site url files. I fired up the page and it says the server has rejected the connection. I wrote to support, but they only wrote to me that port 80 works, but 4043 no longer and they can't help me. In fact, the server was working before the page was launched and even when I fired the page before changing the login details, the page fired and showed a window that there was a connection error with the database. Now it only shows that the server has refused the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I would try installing WP over your current installation first, to make sure it's not a configuration error. Do you have webuzo available? You can install it there. Once you've determined that you can bring the site up, start over with the backup.